# angular select refresh on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a page that has 2 select lists, each populated by a call from a REST service:

```
  var mainApp = angular.module('taxonomyViewer', []);

    mainApp.controller('apiTaxonomyController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.taxonomyList = []; // the taxonomy list for the first select list
        $scope.taxonomyStates = []; // the state list for the taxonomy selected in the first list

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/reports/taxonomies'
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.taxonomyList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
            console.log($scope.taxonomyList);
        });

        $scope.update = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                // api/reports/taxonomies/{ent_id}/states
                url: '/api/reports/taxonomies/' + $scope.selectedItem + '/states'
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.taxonomyStates = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                console.log($scope.taxonomyStates);

            });
            console.log("selected item: " + $scope.selectedItem);
        };
```

My select lists are here:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div ng-app="taxonomyViewer" ng-controller="apiTaxonomyController">
        <select ng-model="selectedItem"
                ng-options="items.ent_id as items.ent_desc for items in taxonomyList"
                ng-change="update()">
            <option value=""> Select Taxonomy </option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div ng-app="taxonomyViewer" ng-controller="apiTaxonomyController">
        <select ng-model="selectedState"
                ng-options="items.ens_guid as items.enk_name + ' - ' + items.sg_name for items in taxonomyStates"
                ng-change="updateState()">
            <option value=""> Select Taxonomy State </option>
        </select>

        <br />
    </div>
    <div id="taxonomyTree" class="fancytree-fade-expander">
    </div>

</div>
```

When you select an item from the first list, the REST service is called and then the second list should populate. The REST service is getting called from inside the $scope.update function but the select list is not loading the $scope.taxonomyStates items.

Comment: Any error messages from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching both your app and controller twice - this creates two apps and two controllers.

When your `update` method grabs the data it is assigning it to `taxonomyStates` on app 1, as that is where `update` is called. However app 2 is the one trying to display it.

```
ng-app="taxonomyViewer" ng-controller="apiTaxonomyController"
```

These attributes should be on the highest DOM element it makes sense for them to be on. Based on this example - I would say `ng-controller` should go on your `col-md-4` `div`, and `ng-app` should almost always be on the `body` or an element directly below.

Comment: That worked thank you. I'm new to angular, so I'm still getting through some of the model.